# Unable to use Kmail : akonadi not operational

Tags: kubuntu, mysql, kmail, akonadi

When i start KMail in Kubuntu 23.04, it says Akonadi personal information manager is not operational. I had recently been setting up mysql for use in amarok. this is what happens when i try to start the service:

```
akonadictl start                                                                                               org.kde.pim.akonadictl: Starting Akonadi Server...
org.kde.pim.akonadictl:    done.
Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)                                                     
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Starting up the Akonadi Server...                                                  
mysqld-akonadi: [ERROR] Failed to open required defaults file: /etc/xdg/akonadi/mysql-global.conf
mysqld-akonadi: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: database server stopped unexpectedly
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Database process exited unexpectedly during initial connection!
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: executable: "/usr/sbin/mysqld-akonadi"
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: arguments: ("--defaults-file=/home/tweak/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf", "--datadir=/home/tweak/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/", "--socket=/run/user/1000/akonadi/mysql.socket", "--pid-file=/run/user/1000/akonadi/mysql.pid")
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: stdout: ""
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: stderr: "mysqld-akonadi: [ERROR] Failed to open required defaults file: /home/tweak/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf\nmysqld-akonadi: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!\n"
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: exit code: 1
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: process error: "Unknown error"
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Shutting down AkonadiServer...
org.kde.pim.akonadicontrol: Application '/usr/bin/akonadiserver' exited normally...
```

How can I recover from this to use kmail again? It does appear that the files exist that it is referencing an error to.

mysql-global.conf :

```
#
# Global Akonadi MySQL server settings,
# These settings can be adjusted using $HOME/.config/akonadi/mysql-local.conf
#
# Based on advice by Kris Köhntopp <kris@mysql.com>
#
[mysqld]

# strict query parsing/interpretation
# TODO: make Akonadi work with those settings enabled
# sql_mode=strict_trans_tables,strict_all_tables,strict_error_for_division_by_zero,no_auto_create_user,no_auto_value_on_zero,no_engine_substitution,no_zero_date,no_zero_in_date,only_full_group_by,pipes_as_concat
# sql_mode=strict_trans_tables

# DEBUGGING:
# log all queries, useful for debugging but generates an enormous amount of data
# log=mysql.full
# log queries slower than n seconds, log file name relative to datadir (for debugging only)
# log_slow_queries=mysql.slow
# long_query_time=1
# log queries not using indices, debug only, disable for production use
# log_queries_not_using_indexes=1
#
# measure database size and adjust innodb_buffer_pool_size
# SELECT sum(data_length) as bla, sum(index_length) as blub FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema not in ("mysql", "information_schema");

# NOTES:
# Keep Innob_log_waits and keep Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free small (see show global status like "inno%", show global variables)

#expire_logs_days=3

#sync_bin_log=0

# Use UTF-8 encoding for tables
character_set_server=utf8
collation_server=utf8_general_ci

# use InnoDB for transactions and better crash recovery
default_storage_engine=innodb

# memory buffer InnoDB uses to cache data and indexes of its tables (default:128M)
# Larger values means less I/O
innodb_buffer_pool_size=128M

# Create a .ibd file for each table (default:0)
innodb_file_per_table=1

# Write out the log buffer to the log file at each commit (default:1)
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2

# Buffer size used to write to the log files on disk (default:1M for builtin, 8M for plugin)
# larger values means less I/O
innodb_log_buffer_size=1M

# Size of each log file in a log group (default:5M) larger means less I/O but more time for recovery.
innodb_log_file_size=64M

# # error log file name, relative to datadir (default:hostname.err)
log_error=mysql.err

# print warnings and connection errors (default:1)
loose_log_warnings=2

# Convert table named to lowercase
lower_case_table_names=1

# Maximum size of one packet or any generated/intermediate string. (default:1M)
max_allowed_packet=32M

# Maximum simultaneous connections allowed (default:100)
max_connections=256

# The two options below make no sense with prepared statements and/or transactions
# (make sense when having the same query multiple times)

# Memory allocated for caching query results (default:0 (disabled))
loose_query_cache_size=0

# Do not cache results (default:1)
loose_query_cache_type=0

# Do not use the privileges mechanisms
skip_grant_tables

# Do not listen for TCP/IP connections at all
skip_networking

# The number of open tables for all threads. (default:64)
table_open_cache=200

# How many threads the server should cache for reuse (default:0)
thread_cache_size=3

# wait 365d before dropping the DB connection (default:8h)
wait_timeout=31536000

# We use InnoDB, so don't let MyISAM eat up memory
key_buffer_size=16K

# KUBUNTU:
# Unset the export dir check as only the full mysql-server package creates it
secure_file_priv=

# KUBUNTU:
# workaround for 5.7 being more strict with column types
# (reverts to 5.6 behavior)
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

[client]
default-character-set=utf8
```

Thank you. I hope I can get this working again~

Comment: What are the permissions on the `mysql-global.conf` file? If they've been updated or are set as inaccessible to the application that requires it, then it could result in the error you're seeing 

Comment: I will check what they are. Any idea how i could find out what they are supposed to be?

Comment: --rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3464 Mar  2  06:53     /etc/xdg/akonadi/mysql-global.conf

Comment: `root:root` files can only be accessed by processes running as the superuser. Are the other files in that directory also `root:root`? If the service runs under a user account, then you may need to change it accordingly (eg: `tweak:tweak`) 

Comment: the directory contains one other file, and it has the same permissions as the other, root:root. mysql-global-mobile.conf. i will try to change the permissions and see if that helps!

Comment: nope same errors. thanks though i appreciate the reply!!

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is: I somehow did not have mariadb installed, which fixed everything.